# Error al actualizar datos ,no actualiza si no agrega en PHP

Tags: php

Estoy realizando un  formulario que intento actualizar los campos, el problema que al actualizar no me actualiza los datos que quiero cambiar si no me inserta  nuevos datos , seria de gran ayuda si me podrían ayudar  donde me equivocado o que errores estoy cometiendo en el código.

todos los demás módulos si me funcionan pero el de actualizar no me ha querido responder.

Mi modelo

```
<?php
    class Registro extends Conectar{

        public function insert_registro($reg_cod,$es_id,$reg_nom,$doc_id,$reg_doc,$reg_edad){
            $conectar= parent::conexion();
            parent::set_names();
            $sql="INSERT INTO tm_registro (reg_id,reg_cod,es_id,reg_nom,doc_id,reg_doc,reg_edad,fech_crea,est) VALUES (NULL,?,?,?,?,?,?,now(),'1');";
            $sql=$conectar->prepare($sql);
            $sql->bindValue(1, $reg_cod);
            $sql->bindValue(2, $es_id);
            $sql->bindValue(3, $reg_nom);
            $sql->bindValue(4, $doc_id);
            $sql->bindValue(5, $reg_doc);
            $sql->bindValue(6, $reg_edad);
            $sql->execute();
            return $resultado=$sql->fetchAll();
        }

        public function update_registro($reg_id,$reg_cod,$es_id,$reg_nom,$doc_id,$reg_doc,$reg_edad){
            $conectar= parent::conexion();
            parent::set_names();
            $sql="UPDATE tm_registro set 
            reg_cod = ?,
            es_id = ?,
            reg_nom = ?,
            doc_id = ?,
            reg_doc = ?,
            reg_edad = ?
            where 
            reg_id=?";
            $sql=$conectar->prepare($sql);
            $sql->bindValue(1, $reg_cod);
            $sql->bindValue(2, $es_id);
            $sql->bindValue(3, $reg_nom);
            $sql->bindValue(4, $doc_id);
            $sql->bindValue(5, $reg_doc);
            $sql->bindValue(6, $reg_edad);
            $sql->bindValue(7, $reg_id);
            $sql->execute();
            return $resultado=$sql->fetchAll();
       
        }
}

?>
```

Mi controlador

```
<?php
    require_once("../config/conexion.php");
    require_once("../models/Registro.php");
    $registro = new Registro();

    switch($_GET["op"]){
        case "guardaryeditar":
            if(empty($_POST["reg_id"])){       
                $registro->insert_registro($_POST["reg_cod"],$_POST["es_id"],$_POST["reg_nom"],$_POST["doc_id"],$_POST["reg_doc"],$_POST["reg_edad"]);
            }
            else{
                $registro->update_registro($_POST["reg_id"],$_POST["reg_cod"],$_POST["es_id"],$_POST["reg_nom"],$_POST["doc_id"],$_POST["reg_doc"],$_POST["reg_edad"]);   
            }
        break;
        
  
                ?>
```

Comment: Ojo, estás ejecutando dos veces `$sql=$conectar->prepare($sql);`. La segunda vez no te devuelve un prepared statement

Comment: gracias estuve haciendo esa verificacion y lo e cambiado pero igual no me actualiza ni un dato solo me hacer el insert y estoy cabezon porque no se el porque

Answer (score 0):

Podrías tener un error en la posición de en que estas enviando tus datos ya que el id **PK** se esta referenciado al ultimo.

Por otra parte podrias intentar actualziarlo de esta forma:

```
$sql="UPDATE tm_registro set  reg_cod = ?, es_id = ?, reg_nom = ?, doc_id = ?, reg_doc = ?, reg_edad = ? where  eg_id=?";
$stmt= $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$reg_cod, $es_id, $reg_nom, $doc_id ,$reg_doc, $reg_edad, $eg_id]);
```

[link de la docuemntación](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/update)

Comment: si estimado y ese cambio pero no encontre que me generara el update